# Storing web links in database

Tags: sql-server, database, http

I have a user comment textarea on a website. I am storing user comments in a SQL Server database. The comments field in the database is of type `nvarchar`.

The problem is with storing the web links (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com) inside a comment. The web links are stored as plain text in the database. They are rendered as plain text on the webpage when comments are retrieved. I want them to be clickable.

How should I store (or render on webpage) a web link?

Comment: Look into using [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) Specifically, [Showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) has a `simplifiedAutoLink` parameter that will convert anything that looks like a URL.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I was able to do this with the help of showdownjs.